# Adding string field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a few point shapefiles. I want to merge them, but first give each point a certain type according to shapefile.

How do I add a String field, all with the same word?

(changing the field type from null to "water")

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field calculator should do what you want.

Toggle the layer to edit mode with [image], then the field calculator icon [image] gets activated.

Create a new field of type string, and type `'water'` (with single quotation marks!) in the input box at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To this I'd add that you should specify the length of your field - it took me a while to figure out why your solution wasn't working until I realised I had forgotten that
[image]